# Online Store Database design?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store some product datas, having same products name, but different specifications.

Like:
Butterfly Valves:
65mm 500INR 15% Iron
85mm 2500INR 85% Iron

Washer:
25mm 100INR 45% Iron
55mm 1500INR 75% Iron.

And again want to fetch in the same way from SQL.

```
<code>

$SelectList =  "SELECT a.p_id, a.dis,a.name,b.p_id,b.rate 
                FROM tst1 a 
                INNER JOIN max b 
                ON a.p_id = b.p_id ";
$Query = mysql_query($SelectList) or die(mysql_error());
$Num_rows = mysql_num_rows($Query);
            $array = array();

while($DataD=mysql_fetch_assoc($Query))
    {

        $sql = "SELECT a.p_id, a.dis,a.name,b.p_id,b.rate 
                FROM tst1 a 
                INNER JOIN max b 
                ON a.p_id = b.p_id WHERE a.name = '".$DataD['name']."'";
        $recset = mysql_query($sql);

        while($Data=mysql_fetch_array($recset)){
            $array['name'][] = $DataD['name'];
            $array['rate'][] = $DataD['rate'];
            $array['dis'][] = $DataD['dis'];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Butterfly Valves:
Butterfly Valves:
65mm 500INR 15% Iron
85mm 2500INR 85% Iron

Washer:
Washer:
25mm 100INR 45% Iron
55mm 1500INR 75% Iron.

Comment: So what is the problem. What is your database design like? Until and unless you make Item Name as your Primary Key which is highly unlikely, you will not have problems in saving the same name twice,thrice or as many times as you want.

Comment: what you have tried for insertion ?

Comment: simple i used two tables for this, one with product ID and description and another with product id and specifications.

Comment: You only need one query.

Comment: Why use two tables? What is the drawback of using one table with Product_ID As Primary Key, Product_Name and Product_Desc??

Comment: which sql query i need to run in this...

Comment: @Neels, i am saving products with same name, but i need to fetch name once and its all details along with name. and next product with its specifications.

Comment: @Strawberry, may i know the query,......

Comment: With the addition of `ORDER BY name`, your first query is the only query you need!

Comment: @Strawberry, i tried it too, but still output is with name and single property, not all....